# React-Router and Meteor fails to render route with parameters on refresh

Tags: node.js, meteor, reactjs, react-router

The app I'm currently working on uses meteor with react and react-router to provide routing capabilities. I have a piece of code that accepts a parameter to the route and renders the item with that ID:

```
<Route path='/ItemView/:itemID' component={ItemView}/>
```

The code works fine from a link which encodes the item id in the path and renders correctly. However, on refresh from the browser or inputting the link by hand in the browser, nothing is renders. It gives the following error:

```
"Exception from Tracker recompute function:" meteor.js:880:10
"TypeError: prevComponentInstance is null"
```

How should I be handling this? Have I not set something up correctly or should I simply be avoiding allowing people to refresh or reload the browser version of a link somehow. This also doesn't happen for non-parameterised links. In those cases refresh works fine with no complaints.

I realise I can use something like Picker to create server side routes but I'm hoping there's something easier I can use.

Full code is available here on the itemview branch:

https://github.com/ClaaziX/foodshare/tree/itemview

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same problem in my app. In my searchings, I stumbled upon this thread on Meteor Forums:

https://forums.meteor.com/t/tracker-crashing-with-react-data-meteor/15287/2

As the reply correctly points out, the error happens because our subscription is not yet ready when the container is created, and fails to return a valid value for the component's prop.

Returning an empty object `{}` instead of `null` or `undefined` (as the database query probably does) should fix the problem